# Is Linked List Palindrome? Confused with Pointing

Tags: c#, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to understand Linked Lists. But I am confused with this question. First code works just fine. It reverse the half of the linked list and compare it to the other part. I totally understand it. However, when I reverse the entire list and compare it to the list that was pointed to it at the beginning, it doesn't work.

First code block works.

```cs
public bool IsPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    
    ListNode slow=head;
    ListNode fast=head;
    
    while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
        slow=slow.next;
        fast=fast.next.next;
    }
    // Point fast to original head. Works w/o any problem
    fast=head;
    slow=Reverse(slow);
    
    while(slow!=null){
        if(slow.val!=fast.val)
            return false;
        slow=slow.next;
        fast=fast.next;
    }
    
    return true;
    
}

public ListNode Reverse(ListNode slow){
     
    ListNode prev=null;
    
    while(slow!=null){
        ListNode next=slow.next;
        slow.next=prev;
        prev=slow;
        slow=next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Second code block doesn't work although it does pretty much the same thing. I reverse the entire list and compare it to the list that points to the original ListNode head. I do not modify head but ListNode slow only.

```cs
public bool IsPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    
    ListNode first=head;
    ListNode second=head;
    
    second=Reverse(second);
    
    while(second!=null && first!=null){
        if(second.val!=first.val)
            return false;
        second=second.next;
        first=first.next;
    }
    
    return true;
}

public ListNode Reverse(ListNode slow){
     
    ListNode prev=null;
    
    while(slow!=null){
        ListNode next=slow.next;
        slow.next=prev;
        prev=slow;
        slow=next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Comment: Side note: It seems like you'd be better off with a doubly linked list.

Comment: _"I do not modify head but ListNode slow only."_ - is `ListNode` a `struct` or `class`?

Comment: it is a class.. I am just confused with pointing. I do not change the original list node head in the second code block but it still fails. In the first code block, I do not change the head either but it doesn't fail. I think there is definitely something with pointing that I do not know much about. I have been trying to find an answer for a few hours but I couldn't.

Comment: Taking your first code block as an example, by the time you reach the `while` loop, `head`, `slow`, and `fast` all point at the exact same block of memory. Which is to say: each of them holds its own reference to the same object.

Comment: The underlying "issue" is the same basis for questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977841/how-do-i-change-my-new-list-without-changing-the-original-list/13977910).

Comment: Does my answer to this question help.  It reverses a linked list in place in O(N): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857536/reverse-a-singly-linkedlist-without-creating-new-linkedlist/62866133#62866133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version does not work because the comparison loop assumes that you now have two lists. But that is not true: the reversal is applied to the list itself, and so the `first` reference will now be referencing the *tail* node, with its `next` reference being `null`. So the loop will stop immediately after the first iteration as `first` will have become `null`. Just think about it: there is just one `next` reference in each node, so you cannot expect to walk through one list in two opposite directions.

One solution is to adapt `Reverse` so it will actually make a new list without altering the original list.

Answer (score 2):

Ted. I had a linked list in a private library and modified it to be kinda like your example. This is a doubly-linked list, so that you can navigate forwards or back - I put a Reverse() function on the ListNodeLinkedList class. I know this isn't exactly like your fast/slow language, but hopefully, it'll help you see the gist of how linked lists function.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string palindrome = "madamimadam"; // madam I'm Adam - the first palindrome. :)

        var linkedList = new ListNodeLinkedList();

        foreach (char c in palindrome.ToCharArray())
        {
            linkedList.AddLast(new ListNode() { Character = c });
        }

        var reverse = linkedList.Reverse();

        if (palindrome == reverse) { Console.WriteLine("success"); }
        else { Console.WriteLine("failure"); }

        // for the record, this is an arbitrary use of a linked list
        // what we're doing here could also be done like this:

        string copy = palindrome;
        copy.Reverse();

        if (palindrome == copy) { Console.WriteLine("simpler success"); }
        else { Console.WriteLine("simpler failure"); }
    }
}

class ListNode
{
    public char Character { get; set; }
    public ListNode Previous { get; set; }
    public ListNode Next { get; set; }
}

class ListNodeLinkedList
{
    private ListNode first = null;
    private ListNode last = null;

    public ListNodeLinkedList()
    { }

    public ListNode First => first;

    public ListNode Last => last;

    public string Reverse()
    {
        List<char> list = new();

        ListNode node = last;

        while (node != null)
        {
            list.Add(node.Character);
            node = node.Previous;
        }

        return new string(list.ToArray());
    }

    public void AddFirst(ListNode node)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }

        if (first == null)
        {
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node.Next = first;
            node.Previous = null;
            first = node;
        }
    }

    public void AddLast(ListNode node)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }

        if (last == null)
        {
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node.Previous = last;
            node.Next = null;
            last.Next = node;
            last = node;
        }
    }

    public void AddAfter(ListNode node, ListNode newNode)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }
        if (newNode == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newNode)); }

        if (last == node) { AddLast(newNode); }
        else
        {
            newNode.Next = node.Next;
            newNode.Previous = node;

            node.Next = newNode;
            newNode.Next.Previous = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void AddBefore(ListNode node, ListNode newNode)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }
        if (newNode == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newNode)); }

        if (first == node) { AddFirst(newNode); }
        else
        {
            newNode.Previous = node.Previous;
            newNode.Next = node;

            node.Previous = newNode;
            newNode.Previous.Next = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveBefore(ListNode node)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }

        node.Previous = node.Previous?.Previous;

        if (node.Previous != null)
        {
            node.Previous.Next = node;
        }

        if (node.Previous == null) { first = node; }
        if (node.Next == null) { last = node; }
    }

    public static void RemoveAfter(ListNode node)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }

        node.Next = node.Next?.Next;

        if (node.Next != null)
        {
            node.Next.Previous = node;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(ListNode node)
    {
        if (node == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }

        if (node == first)
        {
            MakeNodeFirst(first.Next);
        }
        else if (node == last)
        {
            MakeNodeLast(node.Previous);
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.Previous != null)
            {
                node.Previous.Next = node.Next;
            }
            if (node.Next != null)
            {
                node.Next.Previous = node.Previous;
            }
        }
    }

    private void MakeNodeFirst(ListNode node)
    {
        first = node;

        if (first != null)
        {
            first.Previous = null;
        }
    }

    private void MakeNodeLast(ListNode node)
    {
        last = node;
        if (last != null)
        {
            last.Next = null;
        }
    }
}
```